# Doing a like query on a contained entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I've got two tables; People and Pets.

**People**

```
PERSON_ID  PERSON_NAME  FAVORITE_PET
1,         Ryan,        1
```

**Pets**

```
PET_ID  PET_NAME    
1,      Binky
```

A person may or may not have a favorite pet.

I'd like to return all people who have a favorite pet with a name like 'binky'.

In SQL i'd do the following:-

```
SELECT *
  FROM people people, pets pet
 WHERE people.favorite_pet = pet.pet_id
   AND pet.pet_name LIKE 'binky';
```

I've mapped my classes below:-

**Person class**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "people" )
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id @Column( name = "person_id" ) private long personId;
    @Column( name = "person_name" ) private long personName;
    @JoinColumn( name = "favorite_pet" ) @ManyToOne private Pet favoritePet;

}
```

**Pet class**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "pets" )
public class Pet implements Serializable {

    @Id @Column( name = "pet_id" ) private long petId;
    @Column( name = "pet_name" ) private String petName;

}
```

To return the equivalent query i'd expect to do the following DetachedCriteria:-

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass( Person.class );
criteria.add( Restrictions.like( "favoritePet.petName", "binky" ) );
```

However when I do this, I get the following error:-

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: favoritePet.petName of: 
com.test.Person
```

What is the correct approach do this sort of query using restrictions?

Comment: Just as a note, your schema is wrong for this type of data, the Pet table should have an OWNER_ID, the Owner table doesn't need OWNED_PET. Otherwise you will struggle having owners with anything other than 1 pet (possibly 0 if you use NULL). If you want to allow pets to have multiple owners you need a third table to handle the Pet_ID/Owner_ID links

Comment: For a bit of clarity I decided to use the concept of a favorite pet as opposed to a owned pet. What you've mentioned above isn't really the crux of the issue, it's really just a example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're using the Criteria API for such a simple static query, instead of a simple HQL query:

```
select person from Person person where person.favoritePet.name like :name
```

This creates an implicit inner join, and is equivalent to

```
select person from Person person
inner join person.favoritePet pet
where pet.name like :name
```

And you thus also need a joi if you (really) want to do this with a criteria query:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Person.class, "person");
c.createLias("person.favoritePet", "pet"); // inner join
c.add(Restrictions.like("pet.name", name));
```